# (python) Kivy: unwanted black screen

Tags: python, kivy

i'm actually coding an app using kivy lib, and I have a problem on my official code so i created a small debug code (debug.py) with a simple kivy file (debug.kv). When I launch the app, it puts me a black screen. Why ? Thanks.

debug.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class App(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen1()

class Screen1(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def change_screen(self):
        return Screen2()


class Screen2(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def change_screen(self):
        return Screen1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().run()
```

debug.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Screen1>
    Label:
        text:"Screen 1"
    Button:
        text:"Go to screen 2"
        size:(100,300)
        size_hint:(None,None)

        on_press:root.change_screen()

<Screen2>
    Label:
        text:"Screen 2"
    Button:
        text:"Go to screen 1"
        size:(100,300)
        size_hint:(None,None)

        on_press:root.change_screen()
```

____ EDIT ____

How do you change screen from python code ?
Because on my official code, I would like to have a function that checks a password and changes screen only if the password is correct.

Example (that does not work but you can understand my idea):

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):

    def goto2(self):
        root.manager.current = "screen2"
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    def say_hello(self):
        print 'hello2'
    pass

class DebugApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DebugApp().run()
```

.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"Screen 1"
        Button:
            text: "Go to screen 2"
            size: (300,300)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            color:(1,0,0,1)

            on_press: root.goto2()

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
        Button:
            text: "Go to screen 1"
            size: (300,300)
            size_hint: (None,None)
            color:(1,0,0,1)

            on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a black screen, because Kivy was not able to file a Kivy rule file. Please change your class "App(App):" to "DebugApp(App):"

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LoginScreen(Screen):

    def check_password(self, instance, password):
        if password == "pwd":
            instance.current = "screen2"


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Login Screen"

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:
    LoginScreen:
        id: login
    Screen2:

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "screen1"
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
        rows: 3
        padding: 20

        Label:
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.2)
            text:"Password:"
            font_size: 30
            halign: "center"
            valign: "middle"

        TextInput:
            id: password
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.06)
            cursor_blink: True
            font_size: 20
            multiline: False
            password: True

        Button:
            text: "Continue"
            size_hint: (0.2, 0.08)

            on_release:
                root.manager.ids.login.check_password(root.manager, password.text)

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Hello"
        Button:
            text: "Go to screen 1"
            size: (100,300)
            size_hint: (None,None)

            on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about it. Do you know why the "change screen" does not work when clicking button? thx

Comment: I have updated my example to solve your second problem i.e. screen not changing. Please refer to my example for details.

Comment: i have updated my topic (see "EDIT") can you help me please ? thanks

Comment: I have updated my example to prompt user for password and only display screen2 if password is correct. Please refer to my example for details.